# SE Photography Redesign

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I don't know if this is the right place or way to post this, but I wonder if there's anything to proposing a redesign for this site. It's very functional (like all SE sites), but it's hardly had any polish added to it since it was originally designed in 2010. Not to say that it's poorly designed or anything, I've just seen some of the new sites (like [gd.se](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) and [work.se](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)) they've got very clean, bright and fresh designs that would be great to see over here too. I apologize if this inappropriate, but I couldn't help but atleast raise the question.

Answer (score 10):

We're actually in the process of converting existing graduated SE sites to a new LESS(CSS) set up. While we're doing that, we've been giving some older sites some design updates, as well as retina support(svg) for site logos and icons. I'd love to hear some feedback from this community about new design direction. I still love the weekly community photo feature in the header. As for as the main site design goes, I'm definitely open to update logo, and overall look and feel. As for Meta, making it a dark theme was the biggest mistake I made.

Feel free to use this thread to submit design ideas.

Comment: FYI: "dark theme" doesn't mean "bright grey background". The background should be #000.

Answer (score 7):

I agree, we should have a redesign. Our site was designed pretty simply and pretty quickly, without a lot of input from the membership. Personally, I've never cared much for how our meta came out, and overall I think our design could really use some spicing up. Our logo is too simple, I think, it doesn't really speak to photography, it feels more graphic-design like.

We have also had a number of funky issues with the "negative" nature of our meta site that makes soemthings show up incorrectly, difficult to read, etc. Some have been fixed, I don't know that all have.

I don't know how this is done on StackExchange, but a redesign of our site definitely gets my vote.

Comment: A logo that was like a head on view of a camera, where the lens was the focal point would be quite eye catching...

Comment: Do I smell a logo design contest?

Comment: Do people still associate the split prism in the viewfinder with photography? Or would that confuse people who never touched a manual focus body?

Comment: @MichaelT IMHO it would be confusing...but that may just be because I've only used a camera with a split prism once about 12 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Now, I'm actually indifferent to the layout of this site; however, I will ask this one question: why change it?

Are we wanting to change it just to change it, have we had a lot of people complain in meta or chat, or do we want to look closer every other SE site that has just updated?

Again, I'm indifferent on the current layout and I'd like to see some ideas before I say this is a good or bad, but I'd like to know why change it in the first place.